# How to override styles of a library which has its own Activity

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles, android-library

I have a library which has its own Activities with colorPrimary and colorPrimaryDark attributes. In the application which is using this library, there are different values for these color attributes.

Is there a way to make the library use the style provided by the caller application?

So that in the end, if the app has a green toolbar, the activities in the library would have a green toolbar, not the one defined in library theme.

This is the library's theme:

```
<style name="LibraryTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/red</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/dark_red</item>
</style>
```

And this is the sample app's main theme:

```
<style name="SampleAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/green</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/dark_green</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_color</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If "colorPrimary" will use the same value - `@color/primaryColor`, then value of library `primaryColor` will be overridden by `primaryColor` in sample app.

If you will use different values for "colorPrimary" in library and app, for example - `@color/libPrimaryColor` and `@color/appPrimaryColor` then colors will be different

Comment: How about the other attribute like strings. I know it can be done using attrs.xml but then the users will also have to forcefully add these items in their code. Is there any other way to override strings as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can override the theme in your style file,

```
<style name="LibraryTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">Your color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">Your color, too</item>
</style>
```