# Change fontface of components used inside a library project

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles, android-library

Is it possible to change the fontface of components used inside an android library project?

To be more specific: I am using the library '[Onboarder](https://github.com/jrejaud/Onboarder)' to display an introduction when starting the app for the first time. Now i got the requirement to use a certain font wherever text is displayed. With the '[Caligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy)' library i was able to introduce the new font everywhere else.

I already defined a style which applies to TextViews in my own layout files:

```
<style name="TextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="fontPath">fonts/myCustomFont.ttf</item>
</style>
```

The AppTheme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    [...]
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/TextViewStyle</item>
    [...]
</style>
```

The library project also uses plain TextView without any styling, but somehow my styles are not applied to them.

Is there a way to change the font on those TextViews without forking the GitHub repo?

This might be related: [How to override styles of a library which has its own Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35315120/how-to-override-styles-of-a-library-which-has-its-own-activity)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the issue myself:

It was related to the how Calligraphy works. I was lacking a delegate to the CalligraphyContextWrapper in attachBaseContext. Extending the *OnboardingActivity* class and overriding *attachBaseContext()* did the job:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
}
```